# I'm receiving an Error while trying to delete records from CloudKit Public DataBase

Tags: swift, xcode, cloudkit

- I am able to delete records from the CloudKit web interface (in both Development & Production)
- I am able to delete records by code in the development environment
- I Receive an Error massage while deleting by code in the Production environment. (the error message is in the comments below)

I use the following code to delete records:

Comment: Error Message:  <CKError 0x6000009ec480: "Permission Failure" (10/2007); server message = "WRITE operation not permitted"; uuid = 5E9083ED-909F-41A2-A951-D4CB5C2E6444; container ID = "iCloud.com.....">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sign in to the [CloudKit Dashboard](https://icloud.developer.apple.com/dashboard) and review the security rules you have set. Select your CloudKit container (that has your public database in it) in the left nav.

Here are is what you can check:

1. **Container Permissions** - Does the Apple ID you are using on your Mac have permission to access that container?
2. **Security Roles** - Click any link to go into your container (like **Data**). Then click the large, bold text in the upper left (probably set to "Record Types" right now) and select **Security Roles**. Does your role type have permission to `Write` to the record type you are trying to edit?
3. **iOS Simulator** - One common mistake it to not be signed into an iCloud account in the iOS simulator. Be sure to go into the Simulator's **Settings** and sign in.

Comment: I havn't find anything in cloudkit dashboard that change permissions. I am the only developer though and I use my only AppleID here...
besides I can still delete all records from the Development environment , but not from the Production environment..

something might worth mentioning: I have set the users app to set value to the public container of my CloudKit
so I can read them and delete the data later,
these information are statistics related records
i.e.: every time the app is used it sets a record on my public container telling what exactly has been used ..

Comment: Still I can delete records one by one from the Production container of CloudKit web Interface?

Comment: It may help if you show more of your code. Also, since you are attempting to modify multiple records, I suggest sending them all together in a single operation with `CKModifyRecordsOperation`.